# Cloning product not copying custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, terms, duplicates

I have created a custom taxonomy called locations with a lot of options on it. When I clone a product everything is cloned correctly (categories, attributies...) but not the custom taxonomy , all the boxes are untick and I ended up spending too much time ticking them.

I tried you both plugins: duplicate page and duplicate posts, no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you either need to debug the product clone code to work out why it's not copying your taxonomy too, and / or enhance it to do that, or work out how to do this directly in the database so you can fix up cloned products afterwards (if you don't clone products very frequently). I don't know WooCommerce custom taxonomies well enough to help sorry.

Comment: WordPress doesn't have a cloning feature, so this is an issue with those plugins. You will need to discuss it with their authors.

Comment: I see, ok thank you very much.